# NotImplementedError - While trying to run with numba [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

I'm trying to learn how to use numba, so I came up with this simple code:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def my_function():

    my_list = []

    my_list.append(4)
    my_list.append(1)
    my_list.append(6)
    my_list.append(7)
    my_list.append(2)

    print(my_list)    
    del my_list[:]
    return my_list

my_list = my_function()
```

If I run it, it displays this error message:

```
numba.errors.LoweringError: Failed at object (object mode backend)
Internal error:
NotImplementedError: (<class 'numba.ir.DelItem'>, del my_list[$0.29])
File "numba_test.py", line 15
```

Line 15 is the `del my_list[:]` line, but if I remove the `print` statement, the code works just fine. Why is this happening? Is there a way to make it work with the print statement in there?

Comment: This is a bug. Your code works fine if you print a single element of `my_list`. Typically though, you can't print out a full list or array since the `print` statement only supports scalars. I submitted an issue to the numba issue tracker: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1874

Comment: Amending my last statement, you can't print the full list in `nopython` mode. It's fine if you're using object mode.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!